# How to fix the pair_sum function

Tags: python, linked-list

```
class LN:
    def __init__(self,value,next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next  = next

def list_to_ll(l):
   if l == []:
       return None
   front = rear = LN(l[0])
   for v in l[1:]:
       rear.next = LN(v)
       rear = rear.next
   return front

def str_ll(ll):
    answer = ''
    while ll != None:
        answer += str(ll.value)+'->'
        ll = ll.next
    return answer + 'None'

def pair_sum(ll):
    sum = 0
    while ll != None:
        sum == ll.value 
        ll = ll.next
        sum = sum + ll.value
        ll = ll.next 
        return sum
```

I need to write an iterative function named pair_sum (the other three functions cannot be changed); it is passed a linked list (ll) as an argument. It returns a reference to the front of a new linked list that includes the sum of each adjacent pair of values(I cannot use lists, tuples, sets, or dicts in my code). For example if I defined

```
a = list_to_ll([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
pair_sum(a) returns the linked list 
3->7->11->15->None.
```

I need to call

```
ll = list_to_ll([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
print('resulting list             = ',str_ll(pair_sum(ll)))
```

to print the result but it shows the error that "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value' "

How can I fix the pair_sum function?

Comment: What is the purpose of `sum == ll.value` ?

Comment: Also what should `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` actually return?

Comment: Does it _have_ to be an iterative solution? A linked list really _screams_ for a recursive solution...

Comment: Returning `str_ll(pair_sum(ll))` seems to be a non-sense. The function `pair_sum()` return a integer value which can't match with the input of the `str_ll()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your function is that you are not even creating a new `LN`; instead you just calculate a sum. If you really, *really* need an iterative solution, you can try something like this:

```
def pair_sum(ll):
    res = last = LN(ll.value + ll.next.value) if ll.next else LN(ll.value)
    ll = ll.next.next if ll.next else None
    while ll:
        last.next = LN(ll.value + ll.next.value) if ll.next else LN(ll.value)
        ll = ll.next.next if ll.next else None
        last = last.next
    return res
```

Even I have troubles wrapping my head around all those `next` pointers, and I wrote that code. Those ternary `... if ll.next else ...` are there for taking care of odd-numbered lists.

---

Anyway, while you asked for an iterative solution, let me show you a [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) solution instead. The reason for this is that a linked list is a [recursive data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type), and thus lends *much* better to a recursive algorithm, to the effect that such an algorithm often boils down to one or two lines:

```
def pair_sum(ll):
    try:
        # case 1: list has two or more elements left
        return LN(ll.value + ll.next.value, pair_sum(ll.next.next))
    except AttributeError:
        # only one or zero elements left -> return list itself (or None)
        return ll
```

Examples for even and odd numbered lists:

```
>>> pair_sum(list_to_ll([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]))
3->7->11->15->None
>>> pair_sum(list_to_ll([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]))
3->7->11->15->9->None
```

The other (given) parts of the program can also be rewritten much simpler in a recursive manner:

```
class LN:
    def __init__(self,value,next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next  = next

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%r->%r" % (self.value, self.next)

def list_to_ll(l):
    if l:
        front, *rear = l
        return LN(front, list_to_ll(rear))
```

---

Back to the iterative solution. If you really, *really*, **really** need an iterative solution, you could also try this: First, build a reversed version of the result, that can be created from the inside-out, similar to the way the recursive function works. Then inverse that reversed result.

```
def pair_sum(ll):
    reverse = None
    while ll:
        reverse, ll = (LN(ll.value + ll.next.value, reverse), ll.next.next) \
                if ll.next else (LN(ll.value, reverse), None)
    result = None
    while reverse:
        result, reverse = LN(reverse.value, result), reverse.next
    return result
```

IMHO, this version feels a bit more natural and is easier to comprehend, since the linked list has easy access and fast insertion and removal at one end.

Comment: hi, thanks, I just saw your code. for this line 'last.next = LN(ll.value + ll.next.value)'    I got an error that " AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value' ". Did you get the same error? can you tell me to fix it?

Comment: @zeyuxie As I said, the iterative solution did not take odd-numbered lists into account. I now added two alternative versions that do, but I would _really_ recommend using the recursive algorithm. And if your instructor objects, explain to him why the recursive version is better.